# Why isn't there a Times.Always in Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

With Moq, it is possible to verify that a method is **never** called with certain arguments (that is, arguments satisfying certain predicates) using `Times.Never`.

But how to verify that, no mater how many times a method is called, it is **always** called with certain arguments?

The default appears to be `Times.AtLeastOnce`.

There is no `Times.Always`. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Edit: I posted a suggestion to the Moq mailing list last week, but it doesn't look like it's been moderated yet. I'll post any updates here.

Edit: an example. Say I am testing a class which generates XML documents. I want to ensure that only valid documents are generated. In other words, test that the writer dependency is *only ever* given valid documents, with a valid sequence number, to write.

```
should_only_write_valid_xml_documents

Mock.Get(this.writer).Verify(
    w => w.Write(
        It.Is<XDocument>(doc => XsdValidator.IsValid(doc)),
        It.Is<int>(n => n < 3)),
    Times.Always);
```

Comment: "always" implies knowing how many times "always" is, and if you know that why not use Times(n) instead?

Comment: No it doesn't - that's kind of the point of the question. Imagine a method being called in a loop whose size is dynamically determined.

Comment: then inside the loop iteration I'd check the method was called once, again and again and again. that is assuming the loop is in the test code. if it is in the code to be tested instead, then I'd redesign for testability so I can hook into the loop code to check on each method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting "Strict" mock behavior. If the method is called with anything other than the expected parameters, the test will fail.

This is available in Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

(Example taken from the [Moq QuickStart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).)

Every invocation on the mock must now have a corresponding `Setup`.

Using strict mocks tends to lead to brittle tests. I would avoid this technique, or at least use it sparingly.

Comment: Sure - but if it existed, this option allow me to avoid the pain of switching to a strict mock and the additional setup it entails.

Answer (score 8):

And how many times is 'always?'  Moq keeps track of all the times a certain method is called with certain arguments, and then uses that number for comparing to Times.Never, Times.AtLeastOnce, etc.

So, if a method is executed 4 times and you set it to 'Times.Always' what does that even mean?

Times.Never would check to make sure the number is zero.

Times.AtLeastOnce would check that the number is greater than or equal to one.

Times.Always would check that the number is.... ?

You could determine the number of times it SHOULD run programmatically, then do something like:

```
Times.Exactly(calculatedAmount)
```

But there is no way for Moq to know what 'always' means.

Comment: I can't see how this can possibly be true. Moq knows what "never" means - "always" is the inverse of "never". The number you mention would just be compared to the total number of invocations, as opposed to zero.

Comment: @PeteMontgomery Moq knows what "never" means because it means zero.  "Always" is an ambiguous number which could include any positive integer.  Wanting Moq to test that every time a method is called, it was called, seems to be a moot point.  If you are doing execution multiple times (like in a loop), just keep a variable around that represents how many times it should have been called and run a test that tests on Times.Exactly(numTimesShouldRun).

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I think that's either self-contradictory, or misunderstands the point of the question. I'm talking about testing that every time a method is called, it is called *with certain arguments*. See the other answers.

Comment: @PeteMontgomery Given the current behavior, it might be confusing to drop in a Times.Always.  The 'Verify' method states 'Verifies that a specific invocation matching the given expression was performed on the mock.'  Adding a Times.Always value would fundamentally change what the Verify method is doing.  For every other value, it would be normal but for Times.Always it would now also be checking that it WASN'T calling the method with OTHER arguments. If you were to use Verify in the strict sense, 'Always' would be an ambiguous term (as explained in my answer) and therefore not make sense.

Comment: Nonsense, you could say exactly the same thing about Times.Never.

Comment: However, I do take this point: "for Times.Always it would now also be checking that it WASN'T calling the method with OTHER arguments" ...  This is definitely true - but this is exactly what I think might be useful to verify. (But I don't see how that changes the semantics of "Verify" any more than Time.Never!) Pete

Comment: @PeteMontgomery Times.Never just means zero.  So as you are verifying, you are verifying invocation of the given expression zero times.  This is the same behavior as the other 'Times' in that it is testing invocation of the given expression and nothing else (i.e. invocation of the same method with different arguments).  If you add Times.Always you are either changing what Verify is doing or verifying the expression was invoked 'Always' number of times (ambiguous).  In contrast, a 'Times.Even' could be added since it does not change what Verify is doing and is not an ambiguous determination.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply inversion of logic to verify ALWAYS.

E.g.:

Let's say you want to do the following verification:

```
mock.Verify(x => x.Method(It.Is<int>(i => i == 10)), Times.Always());
```

you can simply replace it with:

```
mock.Verify(x => x.Method(It.Is<int>(i => i != 10)), Times.Never());
```

Comment: Hi, the exact motivation for my question is that although you can do this in simple cases, like your example, you can't do it in all cases. For example: verify a method is only ever called with an XML document that satisfies certain criteria. You can't write all possible XML documents that don't satisfy those criteria, so you can't "invert" the verification to use Times.Never.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally wrong on this last point - I just realised that you in general can invert and use Times.Never - provided you are only testing one argument at a time.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a 'fallback' matching for the method with It.IsAny conditions.  You can then verify Times.Never on that matching, which should always have been superseded by the more specific match.

Comment: Could you show how to do that? (Calls to Verify don't "fall through" if that's what you mean - they're independent so far as I can see.) Or do you mean rewrite the test to use use Times.Never? Sometimes that's not possible, because you would have to specify all possible invalid arguments. Cheers, Pete.